# How to set different system locale loaded for different user

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a *Windows Server 2008 R2* platform hosting a website in a cloud service provider. When I remote desktop in as the main administrator account the UI and system locale is set to `Chinese` (convenient for the Chinese freelancers we have working on the project). How do I set it so that it is not system wide as it ask for a system reboot.

I created a new user and placed it in the administrator group but *how do I set it so that whenever this user logs on*, everything is displayed in English while the main administrator user account remains the same and displays Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the english pack and installed it on the server. With my second administrator account, I changed the language under the "Keyboard and Languages" tab to english. Problem solved.

Now my first administrator account will always display windows GUI in chinese while the second one one will display english. Restart of the server was required though as prompted when the setting was changed.